# Find all real $a$ that satisfy the following equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations

$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 ,x_5$ are all real and non-negative. The equations are,

$\sum _{k=1}^5\left(k\cdot x_k\right)=a$

$\sum _{k=1}^5\left(k^3\cdot x_k\right)=a^2$

$\sum _{k=1}^5\left(k^5\cdot x_k\right)=a^3$

I am totally stuck! I have no idea how to do it. I can only go this far:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg) already said:
$$
a^4=a\cdot a^3=\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=1}^5ij^5\cdot x_ix_j =\left(a^2\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=1}^5i^3j^3\cdot x_ix_j
$$
Comparing the coefficients at $x_ix_j=x_jx_i$, we see that they are $ij^5+i^5j$ on the LHS and $2i^3j^3$ on the RHS, and we indeed have $ij^5+i^5j \ge 2i^3j^3 \Leftrightarrow j^4+i^4 \ge 2i^2j^2 \Leftrightarrow \left(i^2-j^2\right)^2\ge 0$. So, we have equality if and only if $i=j$. Therefore, to match the above equation, it must be
$$
x_ix_j=0 \text{ for all } i \ne j
$$
In other words: At most one of the variables can be non-zero (clearly, $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=0$ is a solution if and only if $a=0$). Now, if $k\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with $x_k \ne 0$ and $kx_k=a$, $k^3x_k=a^2$ and $k^5x_k=a^3$, we see that $a=k^2$ and so $x_k=k$. Therefore, we have $6$ solutions in total:
$$\begin{align}
x &= (0,0,0,0,0) \text{ for } a=0\text{,}\\
x &= (1,0,0,0,0) \text{ for } a=1\text{,}\\
x &= (0,2,0,0,0) \text{ for } a=4\text{,}\\
x &= (0,0,3,0,0) \text{ for } a=9\text{,}\\
x &= (0,0,0,4,0) \text{ for } a=16\text{,}\\
\text{and }x &= (0,0,0,0,5) \text{ for } a=25\text{.}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$a^4=\sum_{k=1}^nkx_k\sum_{k=1}^5k^5x_k\geq\left(\sum_{k=1}^5k^3x_k\right)^2=a^4,$$
The equality occurs for $$(\sqrt{x_1},\sqrt{2x_2},...\sqrt{5x_5})||(\sqrt{x_1},\sqrt{32x_2},...,\sqrt{5^5x_5}),$$ which says $$x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Are these cases correct, too?

$x_1 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0 \\
x_1 = x_2 = x_4 = x_5 = 0 \\
x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_5 = 0 \\
x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0$

Comment: @Marchotridyo If $a=0$ only. If $a>0$ and $x_1\neq0$ we have $x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=0$ only.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are:
x1 = 1/2 (a^3 - 5 a^2 + 6 a - 8 x4 - 30 x5),
x2 = 1/2 (-a^3 + 4 a^2 - 3 a + 12 x4 + 40 x5),
x3 = 1/6 (a^3 - 3 a^2 + 2 a - 24 x4 - 60 x5)
x4 independent
x5 independent

and make sure that x1>=0, x2>=0, x3>=0, x4>=0 and x5>=0